# Start/Stop Function Execution jQuery/JS on mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this script to animate the background gradient for a div:
http://codepen.io/quasimondo/pen/lDdrF

Here is what I am trying to achieve:
- on hover run the function to animate gradient background
- on mouse out stop the animation or have it on pause

On CodePen I have replaced line 61 with this:

```
$('#logoCA').hover( function(){
      var gradient = setInterval(updateGradient,2);
    },
    function(){
      clearInterval(gradient);
    });
```

For some reason is not working. Any ideas or better methods?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Move the var outside to make it accessible in the scope: `var gradient; $('#logoCA').hover( function(){
      gradient = setInterval(updateGradient,2);
    },
    function(){
      clearInterval(gradient);
    });`

Comment: `gradient` is **local**. Declare the variable outside of `hover`.

Comment: Great mplungjan - that did the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

So this was the final version:

```
var gradient;

  $('#logoCA').hover( function(){
      gradient = setInterval(updateGradient,2);
      gradient;
    },
    function(){
      clearInterval(gradient);
    });
```

Comment: You do not need the line `gradient;`